# How do I stop the Error message coming up for every line that the searched detail isn't in?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  search = input("Please enter the detail you would like to search for: ")
  file = open("pupildetails.txt")
  for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
      if search in line:
       print(line)
      else:
       print("Error")
```

The line that prints the error message prints it for every line searched detail isn't in #I only want it to print once if none of the lines in the file contain the searched detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather that you *do* want the error message to print if *none* of the file's lines contains the item.  In that case, you might want to set a **found** flag to test *after* you have checked the entire file.

```
found = False
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if search in line:
        print(line)
        found = True

if not found:
    print("Error")
```

If you don't need to print every "success" line, you can make the search a one-liner:

```
found = any(search in line.rstrip() for line in file)
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the lines

```
else:
    print("Error")
```

BTW, the code could be rewritten as

```
search = input("Please enter the detail you would like to search for: ")
with open("pupildetails.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if search in line:
            print(line)
```

Using `with` allows you to make sure the file is closed in any circumstance. Have a look at [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and [this other tutorial](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)

Note: there's no need to strip the whitespace form each line if all you do with it is check the input string is in it